# Why my function that calculates pi number is freezing?

Tags: c#, numerical-methods

I need to calculate `pi` number until 15th digit but my function freezes. I use this Taylor's series:

> [atan(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n} \cdot x^{2n + 1}}{2n + 1}](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=atan(x)%20%3D%20%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cfrac%7B(-1)%5E%7Bn%7D%20%5Ccdot%20x%5E%7B2n%20%2B%201%7D%7D%7B2n%20%2B%201%7D)

[image]

And x equals 1.

There is my function:

```
public static decimal Pi()
{
   decimal curr = 4m, 
   prev = 0m,
   one = -1m,
   den = 3.0m;

   while (Math.Abs(curr - prev) > 1e-15m)
   {
      prev = curr;
      curr += 4.0m * one / den;
      one = -one;
      den += 2.0m;
   }
        
   return curr;
}
```

I have debugged it, but i did't find why. Link to [REPL](https://repl.it/@swimmwatch/calculating-pi)

Comment: `decimal` exists for representing numbers exactly in base 10 that can't be represented in base 2 with fixed precision.  You're representing irrational numbers, so you really shouldn't be using it here.  It's a *lot* slower than base 2 floating point numbers.

Comment: Also, why use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop when you're only using the condition anyway?

Comment: @Servy, yes, while loop is better :) I don't know why i used for loop in that case.

Comment: @Servy, i use `decimal` type for calculating Euler's number but my function doesn't freeze.

Comment: You could add `Console.WriteLine($"{curr} {prev}");` in the while loop, and conclude that your code is not "freezing".

Comment: Try keeping track of the number of iterations and use a smaller epsilon like 1e-2 then 1e-3 and notice that the number of iterations is 2*10^n where n is number of digits of precision you use in epsilon.  So for 15 it's 2 followed by 15 zeros iterations.  That's a lot.  If each iteration takes one nanosecond that would take about 23 days.  Or if each one took 1 tick it would still take over 5 hours to complete.

Comment: @DmitryVasiliev Then apparently your other calculations using `decimal` weren't as performance sensitive, and could afford to be an order of magnitude or more slower and still be fast enough.  You now no longer have the luxury of ignoring such details.

Comment: @Servy Using `double` instead of `decimal` will be faster, but not enough to overcome the fact that the algorithm is exponential.  I was able to calculate about 9 digits with a double in the time it took to do 8 with decimal, but that's still going to put 15 digits in the hours to days category.

Comment: @juharr If that was the only issue it would have been an answer, not a comment.  But a you did confirm that it was a 10x speedup.  It's just that a 10x speedup isn't the only thing they need to change.  That doesn't mean they shouldn't change it though (because that 10x speedup will still be there when they improve their algorithm to require fewer steps).

Comment: Use the Euler-Machin formula or Machin-like formulas to have smaller arguments in the arcus tangent and thus a much more rapid convergence. The Leibniz-Georgy (?) formula is the slowest way to compute pi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the formula,

```
|cur - prev| = 1 / (2n+1) + 1 / (2n-1)
```

Your function should be working correctly, you just have to wait until the 250,000,000,000,000th term. A little of patience (only a few days).

But there is no guarantee that you get 15 exact digits in the end.

---

Never use Leibnitz' formula. Use Machin's variant. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machin-like_formula

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the algorithm is exponential on the number of digits of precision that you want.  To demonstrate I've changed your code a bit to track the number of iterations before we get a result with more and more precision

```
decimal curr = 4m, 
prev = 0m,
one = -1m,
den = 3.0m;

int i = 0;
decimal epsilon = 1;

while(true)
{
  prev = curr;
  curr += 4.0m * one / den;
  one = -one;
  den += 2.0m;
  
  i++;
  
  if(Math.Abs(curr - prev) <= epsilon)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(curr);
    Console.WritleLine(i);
    epsilon /= 10m;
  } 
 
}
```

Here's the resulting output after it gets to 8 digits of precision.

```
3.4666666666666666666666666667
2
3.1891847822775947292439110472
20
3.1465677471829564012877876609
200
3.1420924036835276076022995132
2000
3.1416426510898869869000847891
20000
3.1415976535647933322124871234
200000
3.1415931535895432385563933310
2000000
3.1415927035897907384627370503
20000000
3.1415926585897932134626435385
200000000
```

as you can see each additional digit of percision take 10 times as many iterations and thus 15 digits will take 10,000,000 times as long as it takes to get 8.